Can someone help me find the hole in my $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument? Hint needed (Spivak Chapter 5 Problem 20)

If $f(x)=x$ for rational $x$, and $f(x)=-x$ for irrational $x$,then
$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ does not exist for any $a\neq 0$

Firstly we write down our epsilon delta argument
$$0<|x-a|<\delta\Longrightarrow|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$$
Suppose that $x$ is rational then $|x-l|<\epsilon$ in which case $l=x$ as to satisfy every $\epsilon>0$. Suppose we elect a $x'$ that is irrational and such that $0<|x'-a|<\delta$ for the same $\delta$ as before. Now we have $|-x-l|<\epsilon$, Since $l=x$ we have $|-2x|<\epsilon$ which is not true for every $\epsilon>0$. Therefore the limit $l$ does not exist.
I don't see any immediate holes in my argument. However, I know it must be incorrect because this logic doesn't suggest that a limit exist for $a=0$. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

That's not "the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument", and your first line is not just wrong, it's incoherent.

But $|-2x|\le \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$ if $x\to 0$, right?

A suggestion: Before you try to formalize matters, see if you can argue, informally, why there cannot be a limit at, say, $x = 1$. What stops you from assigning a limit? What are the values taken on by $f(\cdot)$ in a small region around $x = 1$? For example, what is $f(1.01)$? What is $f(1.0314159\ldots)$? And so on.

“… in which case $l=x$ as to satisfy every $\epsilon>0$.” this is invalid. Once you fix an $\epsilon$, the $\delta$ you get from the definition will depend on $\epsilon$, so the values of $x$ that satisfy $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$ will also depend on $\epsilon$. Presumably your thought process went about like this:

Fix any $\epsilon> 0$; there is a $\delta_\epsilon >0$ with
$$0<|x-a|<\delta_\epsilon\implies |f(x)-l|<\epsilon\text{ for any $x\in\mathbb R$}$$
Choose $x_{\delta_\epsilon} $ with $0<| x_{\delta_\epsilon}-a|< \delta_\epsilon $. Then $|f(x_{\delta_\epsilon})-l|<\epsilon$; since $\epsilon>0$ was fixed arbitrarily…

I’ve added subscripts to emphasize each quantity’s dependencies. This hopefully helps show why the best you can say here is that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $x\in\mathbb R$ dependent on $\epsilon$ with $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$.
Another way to see it:
If your proof is correct, then we should be able to reach the conclusion
$$|f(x)-l|<\epsilon\text{ for any $\epsilon>0$}$$
for any choice of $f$ and limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l$ since we only needed the definition of $f$ to write $f(x)=x$. But then we could choose $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{ x}$ (undefined at $0$) and consider the known limit $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$ to say that there’s an $x\neq 0$ with $|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$. This leads to $f(x) =1$ and hence $\frac{\sin(x)}{ x}=1$ for some nonzero $x$, an impossibility.

Apply the Cauchy criterion to disproof the existence of f(a) for $a \neq 0$
$$\exists \epsilon > 0 \,\, , \forall \delta > 0 : |x_1 - a| < \delta  \,\, \text{and} \,\,|x_2 - a| < \delta \implies |f(x_1) - f(x_2) | > \epsilon $$
In particular, choose $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the open interval $(a - \delta , a + \delta)$ such that $x_1$ is rational while $x_2$ is irrational
Then choose $\epsilon = |a|$
Then
$$2a - 2\delta \leq f(x_1) - f(x_2) = x_1 + x_2 \leq 2a + 2 \delta $$
As $\delta \rightarrow 0$ By the squeeze theorem:
$$x_1 + x_2 \rightarrow 2a $$
So,
$$ |x_1 + x_2| = 2|a| \geq |a|$$
Where $2|a| = |a| \iff a = 0$
